# Python/Tkinter- Problems with calling variables from another class and plot graph

Tags: python, variables, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm writing a code in which I need to write some input, do some mathematical operations with them and then print the result. Everything with a GUI!

I wrote the code like this:

```
class Mainwindows:
    def __init__ (self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.mainframe=tk.LabelFrame(self.master, text="INPUT")
        self.outputframe=tk.LabelFrame(self.master, text="OUTPUT")
        self.sinputbutton=tk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Soil INPUT", command=self.opensoilinput)
        self.sinputbutton.pack()
        self.beamimage=tk.PhotoImage(file="Inputfond.pgm")
        self.binputbutton=tk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Beam INPUT",image=self.beamimage, compound="top", command=self.openbeaminput)
        self.binputbutton.pack()
        self.actinputbutton= tk.Button(self.mainframe, text= "Actions INPUT", command= self.openactioninput)
        self.actinputbutton.pack()
        self.glabel=tk.Label(self.mainframe, text= "Beam leinght [m]")
        self.glabel.pack()
        self.glinpute=tk.Entry(self.mainframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.glinpute.pack()
        self.g2label=tk.Label(self.mainframe, text= "Strip leinght [m]")
        self.gl2inpute=tk.Entry(self.mainframe, textvariable= tk.DoubleVar)
        self.gl2inpute.pack()
        self.runbutton=tk.Button(self.outputframe, text="RUN", command=self.runkoenig)
        self.runbutton.pack(side="bottom")
        self.plotbutton=tk.Button(self.outputframe, text="Plot", command= self.plotaction)
        self.plotbutton.pack()
        self.canvplot= tk.Canvas (self.outputframe, width=800, height=600, bg="#60B7FF")
        self.canvplot.pack()
        self.mainframe.pack()
        self.outputframe.pack()

        self.soilwindow= tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.soilwindow.title("Soil INPUT")
        self.app= Soilinput(self.soilwindow)
        self.soilwindow.withdraw()
        self.beamwindow= tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.beamwindow.title("Beam INPUT")
        self.app= Beaminput(self.beamwindow)
        self.beamwindow.withdraw()
        self.actionwindow= tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.actionwindow.title("Actions INPUT")
        self.app= Actioninput(self.actionwindow)
        self.actionwindow.withdraw()

    def opensoilinput(self):
        self.soilwindow.deiconify()
    def openbeaminput(self):
        self.beamwindow.deiconify()
    def openactioninput(self):
        self.actionwindow.deiconify()
    def runkoenig(self):
        self.run= Runkoenig()

    def plotaction(self):
        plt.plot(self.Runkoenig.x, self.Runkoenig.pfin)

class Soilinput:      #1st input window with some widgets
    def __init__ (self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.soilframe=tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.soilstiffness= tk.Label(self.soilframe, text="Soil stiffness [kPa]")
        self.soilstiffness.pack()    
        self.soilstiffnessinpute= tk.Entry(self.soilframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.soilstiffnessinpute.pack()        
        self.deflayer= tk.Label(self.soilframe, text="Deformable layer [m]")
        self.deflayer.pack()        
        self.deflayerinpute= tk.Entry(self.soilframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.deflayerinpute.pack()                
        self.poissonratio=tk.Label(self.soilframe, text="Poisson ratio v")
        self.poissonratio.pack()       
        self.poissonratioinpute=tk.Entry(self.soilframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.poissonratioinpute.pack()       
        self.soilbutton=tk.Button(self.soilframe, text="Ok", command=self.soilinputquit)
        self.soilbutton.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=10)
        self.soilframe.pack()
    def soilinputquit(self):
        self.master.withdraw()

class Beaminput:   #2nd input window with other stuff widget
    def __init__ (self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.beamframe=tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.beamstiffness= tk.Label(self.beamframe, text="Beam stiffness [kPa]")
        self.beamstiffness.pack()
        self.beamstiffnessinpute= tk.Entry(self.beamframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.beamstiffnessinpute.pack()
        self.beaminertia=tk.Label(self.beamframe, text="Beam inertia [kPa]")
        self.beaminertia.pack()
        self.beaminertiainpute= tk.Entry(self.beamframe,textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.beaminertiainpute.pack()
        self.beambase=tk.Label(self.beamframe, text="Beam base [m]")
        self.beambase.pack()
        self.beambaseinpute=tk.Entry(self.beamframe,textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.beambaseinpute.pack()
        self.beamexitbutton=tk.Button(self.beamframe, text="Ok", command=self.beamexit)
        self.beamexitbutton.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=10)
        self.beamframe.pack()
    def beamexit(self):
        self.master.withdraw()

class Actioninput: #3rd and last one of the input windows
    def __init__ (self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.actionframe=tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.actionforce=tk.Label(self.actionframe, text="Nodal Force [kN]")
        self.actionforce.pack()
        self.actionforceinpute= tk.Entry(self.actionframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.actionforceinpute.pack()
        self.actionforcedistance=tk.Label(self.actionframe, text="Node distance [m]")
        self.actionforcedistance.pack()
        self.actionforcedistanceinpute= tk.Entry(self.actionframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.actionforcedistanceinpute.pack()
        self.linearload= tk.Label(self.actionframe, text="Linear Load [kN/m]")
        self.linearload.pack()
        self.linearloadinpute= tk.Entry(self.actionframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.linearloadinpute.pack()
        self.actionexitbutton= tk.Button(self.actionframe, text="Ok", command= self.actionexit)
        self.actionexitbutton.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=10)
        self.actionframe.pack()
    def actionexit(self):
        self.master.withdraw()

class Runkoenig:      #in here i put all the mathematical operations
    def __init__ (self, master):

        self.f=self.actionwindow.actionforceinpute.get()
        self.df= self.actionwindow.actionforcedistanceinpute.get()
        self.E= self.beamwindow.beamstiffnessinpute.get()
        self.J= self.beamwindow.beaminertiainpute.get()
        self.B= self.beamwindow.beambaseinpute.get()
        self.Et= self.soilwindow.soilstiffnessinpute.get()
        self.Hdef= self.soilwindow.deflayeclassrinpute.get()
        self.v= self.soilwindow.poissonratioinpute.get()
        self.L= self.master.glinpute.get()
        self.l= self.master.gl2inpute.get()
        self.x=(0.5*self.l*(2*self.NaSTR-self.Nuno));

        #math stuff stuff stuff and then the final passages:

        self.p=np.linalg.solve(self.A,self.N)
        self.pfin=np.resize(self.p,np.size(self.x))

def main():    
     root=tk.Tk()
     root.title("$$$$$")
     app= Mainwindows(root)
     root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

What I want to do is to insert the inputs in the entry widgets stored in the input windows , then come back to the root, push the button RUN to start all those mathematical operations written in the "Runkoenig" class and then push the button "plot" to show the plot of "x" and "pfin" in the canvas.

Except from the canvas thing (I wrote nothing because don't know how to do it) it doesn't work anyway!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting errors? If so, what errors? If no errors, how is the behavior you see different than what you want? Also, the indentation of your code needs to be fixed.

Comment: There is _way_ too much code here.  The simpler and more concise you can make your question the more likely you will get an answer.  People here tend to be very happy to help you, but are less willing to do all of your debugging for you.

Comment: I fixed the indentation, However when I hit the Run Button it tells me:

line 61, in runkoenig
    self.run = Runkoenig()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'

Comment: Sorry for the code leinght but I can't really cut much if I want to explain the problem correctly, maybe some labels which are not necessary but it won't change it's leinght so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes can't magically access each other's attributes. Here's a slightly modified version of your code. Obviously, I can't test it properly, but it should help you to get things working.

The main thing I've done is to save each of the subsidiary class instances in  `Mainwindows`; your code was kind of doing that, with `self.app`, but each new instance was over-writing the previous one. So now the `Soilinput` instance gets saved to the `.soil` attribute of the `Mainwindows` instance. Etc.

Also, I pass the `Mainwindows` instance to `Runkoenig` so that `Runkoenig` can access `Mainwindows` directly, and it can also access the subsidiary instances from the attributes saved in `Mainwindows`.

Inside any method of `Mainwindows` the name `self` refers to the `Mainwindows` instance itself. When the `RUN` button is pressed the `.runkoenig` method of the `Mainwindows` instance is called. That method creates a new `Runkoenig` instance, passing it the `Mainwindows` `self`.

In other words, `Runkoenig(self)` passes a reference to the `Mainwindows` instance to the `Runkoenig` `.__init__` method. That `__init__` method  receives that reference as its second parameter, `mainwin`, so inside that method `mainwin` is a reference to our `Mainwindows` instance. I hope that wasn't too confusing. :)

```
import Tkinter as tk 

class Mainwindows:
    def __init__ (self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.mainframe=tk.LabelFrame(self.master, text="INPUT")
        self.outputframe=tk.LabelFrame(self.master, text="OUTPUT")
        self.sinputbutton=tk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Soil INPUT", command=self.opensoilinput)
        self.sinputbutton.pack()
        #self.beamimage=tk.PhotoImage(file="Inputfond.pgm")
        #self.binputbutton=tk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Beam INPUT",image=self.beamimage, compound="top", command=self.openbeaminput)

        self.binputbutton=tk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Beam INPUT", compound="top", command=self.openbeaminput)

        self.binputbutton.pack()
        self.actinputbutton= tk.Button(self.mainframe, text= "Actions INPUT", command= self.openactioninput)
        self.actinputbutton.pack()
        self.glabel=tk.Label(self.mainframe, text= "Beam leinght [m]")
        self.glabel.pack()
        self.glinpute=tk.Entry(self.mainframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.glinpute.pack()
        self.g2label=tk.Label(self.mainframe, text= "Strip leinght [m]")
        self.g2label.pack()        
        self.gl2inpute=tk.Entry(self.mainframe, textvariable= tk.DoubleVar)
        self.gl2inpute.pack()
        self.runbutton=tk.Button(self.outputframe, text="RUN", command=self.runkoenig)
        self.runbutton.pack(side="bottom")
        self.plotbutton=tk.Button(self.outputframe, text="Plot", command= self.plotaction)
        self.plotbutton.pack()
        self.canvplot= tk.Canvas (self.outputframe, width=800, height=600, bg="#60B7FF")
        self.canvplot.pack()
        self.mainframe.pack()
        self.outputframe.pack()

        self.soilwindow= tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.soilwindow.title("Soil INPUT")
        self.soil = Soilinput(self.soilwindow)
        self.soilwindow.withdraw()
        self.beamwindow= tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.beamwindow.title("Beam INPUT")
        self.beam = Beaminput(self.beamwindow)
        self.beamwindow.withdraw()
        self.actionwindow= tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.actionwindow.title("Actions INPUT")
        self.action = Actioninput(self.actionwindow)
        self.actionwindow.withdraw()

    def opensoilinput(self):
        self.soilwindow.deiconify()
    def openbeaminput(self):
        self.beamwindow.deiconify()
    def openactioninput(self):
        self.actionwindow.deiconify()
    def runkoenig(self):
        self.run = Runkoenig(self)

    def plotaction(self):
        plt.plot(self.Runkoenig.x, self.Runkoenig.pfin)

class Soilinput:      #1st input window with some widgets
    def __init__ (self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.soilframe=tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.soilstiffness= tk.Label(self.soilframe, text="Soil stiffness [kPa]")
        self.soilstiffness.pack()    
        self.soilstiffnessinpute= tk.Entry(self.soilframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.soilstiffnessinpute.pack()        
        self.deflayer= tk.Label(self.soilframe, text="Deformable layer [m]")
        self.deflayer.pack()        
        self.deflayerinpute= tk.Entry(self.soilframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.deflayerinpute.pack()                
        self.poissonratio=tk.Label(self.soilframe, text="Poisson ratio v")
        self.poissonratio.pack()       
        self.poissonratioinpute=tk.Entry(self.soilframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.poissonratioinpute.pack()       
        self.soilbutton=tk.Button(self.soilframe, text="Ok", command=self.soilinputquit)
        self.soilbutton.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=10)
        self.soilframe.pack()
    def soilinputquit(self):
        self.master.withdraw()

class Beaminput:   #2nd input window with other stuff widget
    def __init__ (self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.beamframe=tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.beamstiffness= tk.Label(self.beamframe, text="Beam stiffness [kPa]")
        self.beamstiffness.pack()
        self.beamstiffnessinpute= tk.Entry(self.beamframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.beamstiffnessinpute.pack()
        self.beaminertia=tk.Label(self.beamframe, text="Beam inertia [kPa]")
        self.beaminertia.pack()
        self.beaminertiainpute= tk.Entry(self.beamframe,textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.beaminertiainpute.pack()
        self.beambase=tk.Label(self.beamframe, text="Beam base [m]")
        self.beambase.pack()
        self.beambaseinpute=tk.Entry(self.beamframe,textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.beambaseinpute.pack()
        self.beamexitbutton=tk.Button(self.beamframe, text="Ok", command=self.beamexit)
        self.beamexitbutton.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=10)
        self.beamframe.pack()
    def beamexit(self):
        self.master.withdraw()

class Actioninput: #3rd and last one of the input windows
    def __init__ (self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.actionframe=tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.actionforce=tk.Label(self.actionframe, text="Nodal Force [kN]")
        self.actionforce.pack()
        self.actionforceinpute= tk.Entry(self.actionframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.actionforceinpute.pack()
        self.actionforcedistance=tk.Label(self.actionframe, text="Node distance [m]")
        self.actionforcedistance.pack()
        self.actionforcedistanceinpute= tk.Entry(self.actionframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.actionforcedistanceinpute.pack()
        self.linearload= tk.Label(self.actionframe, text="Linear Load [kN/m]")
        self.linearload.pack()
        self.linearloadinpute= tk.Entry(self.actionframe, textvariable=tk.DoubleVar)
        self.linearloadinpute.pack()
        self.actionexitbutton= tk.Button(self.actionframe, text="Ok", command= self.actionexit)
        self.actionexitbutton.pack(side="right", padx=5, pady=10)
        self.actionframe.pack()
    def actionexit(self):
        self.master.withdraw()

class Runkoenig:      #in here i put all the mathematical operations
    def __init__ (self, mainwin):
        self.f=mainwin.action.actionforceinpute.get()
        self.df= mainwin.action.actionforcedistanceinpute.get()
        self.E= mainwin.beam.beamstiffnessinpute.get()
        self.J= mainwin.beam.beaminertiainpute.get()
        self.B= mainwin.beam.beambaseinpute.get()
        self.Et= mainwin.soil.soilstiffnessinpute.get()
        self.Hdef= mainwin.soil.deflayerinpute.get()
        self.v= mainwin.soil.poissonratioinpute.get()
        self.L= mainwin.glinpute.get()
        self.l= mainwin.gl2inpute.get()
        print("ok!")

        #self.x=(0.5*self.l*(2*self.NaSTR-self.Nuno));

        #math stuff stuff stuff and then the final passages:

        #self.p=np.linalg.solve(self.A,self.N)
        #self.pfin=np.resize(self.p,np.size(self.x))

def main():    
     root=tk.Tk()
     root.title("$$$$$")
     app= Mainwindows(root)
     root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I used a simplified version of `self.binputbutton` since I don't have the "Inputfond.pgm" image file.

---

Next time, please consider posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); it makes life *so* much simpler for people attempting to answer your question. And it's possible that you can solve the problem yourself in the process of creating the MCVE.

Comment: When you pass the `Mainwindow` instance to `Runkoenig` you write something like `def __init__ (self, mainwin)` and then you use this `mainwin.etc` to tell him ok look into Mainwindow class, but I can't understand the entire process, I mean don't you need to define something like `mainwin= Mainwindow` to tell him that mainwin means that class? I know your code works but would like to understand for the future! Thank you!

Comment: So as I write `self.class2= Class2` into another class for example `Class1` and then I create Class 2 with two parameters in the `__init__` which could be : `(self, whateveriwant)`; I'm telling Class 2 :  self means yourself ! and the second parameter means : I got an istance of yourself into another class, look at that class as I write `whateveriwant` before something in Class 2. So I realize the bind when I write an istance of Class2 into Class 1 and then I give a name to the second parameter in init. Am I right?

Comment: @nearchos: That's pretty close. :) I suggest you make a couple of _simple_ non-GUI classes and try some experiments with them, using `print` to see what's getting passed around.

Comment: I did it. One last question, if I want to do that thing but with multiple classes let's suppose i got `Class1` ---> `self.class3= Class3` and then `Class2` ---> `self.class3= Class3` do I simply write a 3rd parameter in Class 3 's init like `__init__ (self, lookfor1, lookfor2)` or is more complicated?

Comment: @nearchos: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do there. I think you want `Class1` and `Class2` to both have access to the same instance of `Class3`, and you want the `Class3` instance to have access to the `Class1` and `Class2` instances . If so, then one of `Class1` or `Class2` should create the  `Class3` instance, passing a reference of itself and  a reference of the other class instance to `Class3`. Try to create a simple example yourself, and if you can't get it to work like you want ask a new question.